# how to change git folder from previous to new?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

**Having problem in using the same repository previously used**

I was trying some new stuff with my rails project and ended up losing its major functionalities, but I git my project on GitHub. So i downloaded from there and now when I made some changes to this newly downloaded file, I cant git to same repo now. How to git into that same repository. Like it has 8 commits now and now if I do my another commit it should be the 9th. Any help?

Hope the problem is clear..

Comment: "Hope the problem is clear" - not particularly. How did you download your project from github? With `git clone`?

Comment: yes i downloaded via clone. and a zip file downloaded

Comment: Downloading zip file is something different than cloning the repo. Did you do both of these actions?

Comment: @djmayank you need to attach git url again `git remote add origin git@github.com:sample/sample.git`

Comment: i think no i have just downloaded zip file

Comment: @7urkm3n after changing it gives this error "Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

Comment: @djmayank then the repo is not belongs to you i think, you need to create new repo for yrself.

Comment: no its my repository only.

Comment: git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
 what this means , how to check its on which repository?

Comment: reclone to a new directory and work there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to install `git` on your device
2. Then open `terminal` and type : `git clone "the url of your repo on your git account"`
3. Enter your `git` password
4. After `cloning` the app you have to add your `branch`. If you just have `master branch` you don't need to do any thing change your code and then
5. Enter `git status` , `git add "file path"` , `git push origin master`
6. Now you can see your `commit` and your `changes` on your `git` account!

   - for checking the remote press : `git remote -v`
   - for setting the correct url : `git remote set-url origin "the repo path"`